# plots of all feature distributions by class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distribution

I want to plot the distribution of features in my dataset, So I go like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = ['P'] * 250 + ['Q'] * 350 + ['R'] * 200
y = np.random.randn(800)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code':x, 'Value':y})

df['Value'].hist(by=df['Code'])
```

Output:

But I would like to impose the same scaling on axes in both feature plots, so it is easy to compare.

[image]

Comment: Add `sharey=True`?

Comment: 2 are scaled (0, 20 , 40) the other (0, 25, 50 ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html), use `sharey=True`:

> **sharey** : *bool, default False*
>
> In case subplots=True, share y axis and set some y axis labels to invisible.